# Quasiconvexity of the objective function

Tags: analysis, karush-kuhn-tucker, hessian-matrix

I´m having a lot of trouble showing if the objective function is quasiconvex or not. I already tried with the bordered Hessian but it gets really messy :-/. Maybe someone can help me with this! Thanks in advance!

The problem: $$max f(x,y)=x^{1/2}*y^{1/3}$$

subject to:$$3x+4y ≤25$$

Answer (score 1):

This is not a quasiconvex function but a strictly quasiconcave function. This is a Cobb-Douglas function with $\alpha = 1/2$ and $\beta = 1/3$. Thus $\alpha + \beta = 5/6$ which is less than 1. Thus the Cobb-Douglas function $x^{1/2}*y^{1/3}$ is concave and therefore it is also quasiconcave. The fact that it is strictly quasiconcave can be shown by solving the Bordered Hessian.

Answer (score 0):

Make up the generalized Lagrange function:

$L=x^{\frac{1}{2}}y^{\frac{1}{3}}+\lambda(25-3x-4y).$

Kuhn-Tucker conditions for Maximum:

$L_x=\frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}y^{\frac{1}{3}}-3\lambda\leq0,\quad x\geq0, \quad xL_x=0;$

$L_y=\frac{1}{3}x^{\frac{1}{2}}y^{-\frac{2}{3}}-4\lambda\leq0,\quad y\geq0, \quad yL_y=0;$

$L_{\lambda}=25-3x-4y\geq0,\quad \lambda\geq0, \quad \lambda L_{\lambda}=0.$

Cases:

1) $x,y,\lambda>0 \Rightarrow \begin{cases}
L_x=0, \\
L_y=0, \\
L_{\lambda}=0
\end{cases} \Rightarrow (x,y)=(5,2.5)\Rightarrow f=5^{\frac{5}{6}}\cdot2^{-\frac{1}{3}} (max).$

2) $x=0,y>0\Rightarrow f=0.$

3) $x>0,y=0\Rightarrow f=0.$

4) $x=0,y=0\Rightarrow f=0.$